# Messy Chinese filenames in FormData

Tags: javascript, form-data

I used the following js code to load a file with a Chinese filename into FormData and then upload it and found the filename garbled on the server side.

```
export async function uploadFile(file, url) {
    let formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('file', file.file)
    file.status = 'loading'
    let response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData})

    file.status = response.ok
    return response
}
```

How can I solve the filename garbling problem because the filenames in formdata seem to be ASCII encoded?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce any such issue](https://jsfiddle.net/kgz2ye0q/). What encoding are you using client-side? How is your API configured?

Comment: @Phil My environment is vite3+vue3, I also see the correct Chinese filename in the developer tools of the browser, but uploading to the server side is just messy. Then I tested the server port with postman and it showed the correct Chinese filename, which means it's a front-end problem. As it turns out, the file that FormData uploads in my case is an ASCII encoded filename, no matter how correctly it is displayed in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is used to share my solution. The code is below. I encoded the file name with `encodeURIComponent` and created a new `File Object` from it.

```
export async function uploadFile(file, url) {
    let formData = new FormData()
    const file_ = new File([file.file], encodeURIComponent(file.filename), {type: file.file.type});

    formData.append('file', file_)
    file.status = 'loading'
    let response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: formData})
    

    file.status = response.ok
    return response
}
```

Afterwards I decode the filename with `decodeURIComponent` on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

[FormData accepts 3rd parameter as `filename`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) and it should be URI-encoded according to [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266#section-4.3) so that the part of formData.append part of code above could be:

```
formData.append('file', file.file, encodeURIComponent(file.name))
```

(no need to create `file_` variable).